# IllegalStateException in second instance of Grails app in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, grails

I've deployed two instances of the same Grails app in Tomcat7. I've used the following to create wars, using environments in config files:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=instance1 war
grails -Dgrails.env=instance2 war
```

I use setenv.sh for extra configurations and settings for JAVA_OPTS.

First instance runs correctly. The second gives me the following error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /instance2/
Class
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message
    No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Trace

    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I've tried to deploy a third instance with a different name. It works correctly. So I've undeployed and redeployed it into Tomcat, but it does not work...
I'm going crazy, because it seems that the app name has an influence...

I've deployed the application using the following:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=nameofapp war
```

where `nameofapp` is the name of the application

I'm using Grails 2.2.1 version

EDIT 2:

I've understood that the problem occurs when an app is deployed for the first time. Infact, when first deploy into Tomcat occurs, I see the following in catalina.out:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at medicalofficemanager.SecUserSecRole.create(SecUserSecRole.groovy:32)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:61)
at         grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/MyAppName] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@d5381] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [myapp.SecRole.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@13e45] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:49:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyAppName] appears to have started a thread named [aclCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 18, 2015 5:51:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore.keySet(CompoundStore.java:216)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.factories.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I think that first exception (about SecUserSecRole) it is not relevant...
If I undeploy and redeploy the same war, without cleaning the database, the application starts correctly.
What about this stacktrace?

Comment: anyone with helpful suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be in SecUserSecRole.groovy:32. I'd be willing to bet that is the spot where your app first tries to do DB access.  Can you post the relevant section of SecUserSecRole.groovy as well as details on your DB configuration?

Comment: I've solved checking the line you've suggested. In production there were no stacktrace so I've run in development and I've solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yea, How did you solve it. It would be helpful for other who may run into the same issue, like myself :)

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in this line: grails -Dgrails.env=instance1 war

-Dgrails.env should be set to the environment name eg: dev, test, prod or myCustomEnv, not the name of the application.

This setting tells Grails to look up the settings in the environment section of  DataSource.groovy and Config.groovy under the name supplied and apply them.  If they do not exist who knows what you will end up with.

As you can see in your stacktrace you are getting a null pointer exception when Grails is trying to execute the environment block.  This is because the value you have given it does not exist.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong... I should write nameOfEnv and not nameOfApp!